# Discord Webhook Send Message with Components

Tags: php, curl, discord, components, webhooks

I am trying to send a message to Discord Webhook, with Components.

I have tried normal message and embed, and both give me the same result.  I get the message, but not the components.

Syntax From here:  https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components

[image: Discord Output]

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1234567890";

$content = '{
            "content": "This is a message with components.",
            "components": [
                {
                    "type": 1,
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "type": 2,
                            "label": "Click me!",
                            "style": 1,
                            "custom_id": "click_one"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
    }';

$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json');
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  $content,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_HEADER   => true
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($response);
```

Here is the var_dump of the response:
[image: HTTP Response]

Comment: Is your webhook "application owned"? According to https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook, supplying `components` requires that to be the case.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, but how to I application-own a webhook? I cant find any information on it

Comment: Don't know, sorry. https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook mentions a bit more about it, but I don't see a way to _set_ the type when creating one.